# How to pass an image to a view controller programatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I tried to pass an image to a view controller like following,

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
CropViewController *vc = (CropViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CropViewController"];
vc.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:jpegData];
// present
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

using this it's presenting to the desired view controller well. But the image that I've set, it's not added to the image view. Is there any way to fix this? Why is this happening?

Thanks in Advance1

Comment: Is `vc.image` `nil`?

Comment: nope. It's not nil..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
CropViewController *vc = (CropViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CropViewController"];
// present
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:(^{
    vc.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:jpegData];
})];
```

VC's view hierarchy was not set up